# Plugin to Copy Files from Desktop to Jobs Workspace in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a scenario wherein the users who have created some configuration files need to upload the same from the desktop where they access Jenkins onto the Job's workspace to build and execute tests.

So I did try using the *Config File Provider* plugin as mentioned in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin. This seems to work fine to copy the configuration file to the Jenkins UI, which can be later synced to the Slave with the given path in the *Build environment* of the respective job. But the users who wish to upload these files don't have the administrative rights. Hence they are unable to access the *Configuration File Management* which is under the *Manage Jenkins* tab. Is there any way that I can move the *Configuration File Management* under the Jenkins sidebar and allow users to edit the same.

Are there any other plugins that will help me achieve the same? I did also try *Copy to Slave* plugin but this only copies the files under $JENKINS_HOME/userContent to the job's workspace. We will have to copy the files from the desktop to $JENKINS_HOME/userContent and then use the plugin.

Comment: Might be too obvious... but can't you load the configuration file by fetching it from git or your scm of choice? The job would then do the following: scm fetch configuration file (one build step), second step env-inject the just loaded file, 3 do whatever you need in the next steps.  By using an scm, developers only need to push their change into the repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wouldn't using a parameterized job and have one of the parameters be a File Parameter?  See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: File parameter in Parameterized build may allows a build to accept a file, to be submitted by the user when scheduling a new build. But the only concern again is the file should be placed inside the workspace at the known location after the check-out/update is done, so that your build scripts can use this file. But my requirement is the users config file needs to be updated from any machine where the user is accessing the Jenkins.

Comment: Any file uploaded in place of a File Parameter is placed into the workspace.  I believe it's always placed at the root of the workspace, with a file name that matches the parameter name.  So even if you upload a file with a different name, it will be renamed to match the parameter.  And since the upload occurs from whatever machine started the build, the file will come from potentially any number of machines.  Unless I misunderstood the intent...

Comment: what happens if the file is maintained in git, does it get merged to the previous file or it replaces the whole file and commits it in workspace master? Kindly let me know

Comment: @karthik27, a Jenkins file parameter is never merged - it is is just present.  It won't be merged or committed if a git workspace happens to overlap.  Actually, I'm not sure which action would be performed first - will the file be copied into the workspace and then the SCM checked out?  Or will the SCM be checked out and then the file parameter created.  Either way - not safe.